# Wireless keeps disconnecting every 5 minutes

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell, 17.10

I have a new Dell XPS 15 running Ubuntu 17.10. My wireless keeps disconnecting every five minutes, so I have to manually disconnect and reconnect.

This is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

This is the output of `uname -ar`.

```
Linux server1 4.13.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the hardware information from `sudo lshw -short`.

```
H/W path       Device  Class          Description
=================================================
                       system         XPS 15 9560 (07BE)
/0                     bus            05FFDN
/0/0                   memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/45                  memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/45/0                memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/45/1                memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/49                  memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/4a                  memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/4b                  memory         6MiB L3 cache
/0/4c                  processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
/0/100                 bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1               bridge         Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0             display        GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
/0/100/2               display        Intel Corporation
/0/100/4               generic        Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/14              bus            Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0    usb1    bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1          input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/4          communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/0/c          multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
/0/100/14/1    usb2    bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2            generic        Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
/0/100/15              generic        Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/15.1            generic        Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1
/0/100/16              communication  Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17              storage        Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1c              bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c/0    wlp2s0  network        QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/1c.1            bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2
/0/100/1c.1/0          generic        RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1d              bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1d/0            storage        Toshiba America Info Systems
/0/100/1d.4            bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13
/0/100/1d.6            bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #15
/0/100/1f              bridge         Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2            memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3            multimedia     Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.4            bus            Sunrise Point-H SMBus
/1                     power          DELL GPM0365
```

`lsusb` reports these USB controllers.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is the full output of `lspci -knn`.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:5910] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1028:07be]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [8086:a131] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a160] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:a161] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 [8086:a13a] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a103] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:a110] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 [8086:a111] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:a118] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 [8086:a11c] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #15 [8086:a11e] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [8086:a152] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [1028:07be]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC [8086:a121] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H PMC [1028:07be]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a171] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus [8086:a123] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-H SMBus [1028:07be]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [1028:07be]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0115] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0001]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

Please help me with this annoying issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot comment, I'm writing an answer.

I'm quite sure that this is a duplicate of [WiFi unstable after 17.10 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967355/wifi-unstable-after-17-10-update).

The solution is to upgrade the firmware from the repository maintained by Qualcomm at https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.

Comment: how can I install the new firmware? i couldn't find any install instructions. could you please help?

Comment: I wrote more detailed instructions in the linked question. If you need more help, then ask.

Answer (score 0):

I would disable wifi power managent and see how it works

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

Comment: i tried this, but it gets disconnected again and again.... the problem persists

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665) and edit the question to include the results, you can upload the contents to paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL