# Wifi problem, connection stops working

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10

I have dualbooted my Windows 10 with ubuntu.
However my wifi just stops working from time to time. The weird thing is that I am still connected to the wifi (logo shows that I am connected). What I can do to fix it is go to the settings and press the wifi I am on for a couple of times so it connects again. 
This is really annoying. And it happens a couple of times per hour.

I am using ubuntu 17.10

I am using a Acer Aspire A715-71G-76Z5 laptop.

output of `lspci -knn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:5910] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1025:119b]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:119b]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1025:119b]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [8086:a131] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [1025:119b]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a160] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller [1025:119b]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:a161] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller [1025:119b]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 [8086:a13a] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI [1025:119b]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a103] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1025:119b]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:a112] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:a113] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:a118] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [8086:a152] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [1025:119b]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC [8086:a121] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H PMC [1025:119b]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a171] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:119b]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus [8086:a123] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-H SMBus [1025:119b]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [1025:1197]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0807]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader [1025:119b]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:119b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:f1a5] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:390a]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

Output of uname -a

```
Linux User 4.13.0-25-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 8 21:14:41 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please post some more info. Are you using a Laptop? Whats the Network / Wireless output of `lspci -knn`. What kernel are you using: `uname -a`. One cause could be wifi-powermanagement. But this might not be the only cause. Also it's better to stick with Ubuntu LTS versions like 16.04

Comment: I updated my post!

Comment: Maybe here is a solution for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967355/wifi-unstable-after-17-10-update
He has the same wifi card `QCA6174`, same driver `ath10k_pci` and 17.10

Comment: I tried it out for a couple of days and unfortunately this didn't solve my problem this is really a pain in the ass because I am using this for my work, and my wifi keeps cutting out.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux You said the cause might be wifi-powermanagment right? I see that wifi-powermanagment is turned on. Could this be the problem?

Comment: people have reported wifi-powermanagement to cause problems sometimes.